# Automatically simplify redundant arithmetic relations

Tags: python, matlab, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I am looking for a way to automatically determine, e.g., that `(a < 12) & (a < 3) & (c >= 4)` is the same as `(a < 3) & (c >= 4)`. I looked into Matlab's symbolic toolbox and SymPy in Python, but these are apparently only capable of simplifying purely Boolean logic (e.g., `simplify(a & b | b & a) -> ans=(a & b)`)

Is there a way of using these symbolic math tools like described above?

**Edit**

As noted in the comment to @user12750353's answer, I would like to also simplify systems of relations that are concatenated with a Boolean OR, e.g., `((a < 12) & (a < 3) & (c >= 4)) | (a < 1)`.

Comment: Shouldn't the first expression be congruent to `(a < 12) & (c >= 4)`? Mathematically, this would make more sense, because all solutions of **a < 3** are solutions of **a < 12**. Or, are we looking for the intersection of the inequalities, i.e. **a < 12 ∩ a < 3**?

Comment: FWIW you can try `fourier_elim` in [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io) which implements a version of [Fourier-Motzkin elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination).

Comment: Is it always simple relational expressions like in your example?  I think you can try using equivalents, like (a < 12) is the same as max(a+1,12)==12 (assuming a is an integer)

Comment: Actually, it seems like SymPy is buggy when it comes to using the max function in that way.  Here, I'm testing it with (a <= 4) & (a <= 6) and it simplifies it to always False!  `simplify(Eq(Max(4, a), 4) & Eq(Max(6, a), 6))`  =>  `False`.  But if I evaluate that expression instead of simplifying it  `(Eq(Max(6,a),6) & Eq(Max(4,a),4)).subs({a:3})`  I get `True`

Comment: @JacobLee: `(a < 12) & (a < 3)` is true when `a < 3`, not for larger values of `a`. The `&` operator is the Boolean AND, and corresponds to an intersection, not a union. OP is looking for a simplified expression that yields the same result for any given input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy sets can be used to do univariate simplification, e.g. `((x < 3) & (x < 5)).as_set() -> Interval.open(-oo, 3)` and sets can be converted back to relationals. The following converts a complex expression to cnf form, separates args with respect to free symbols and simplifies those that are univariate while leaving multivariate arguments unchanged.

```
def f(eq):
    from collections import defaultdict
    from sympy import to_cnf, ordered
    cnf = to_cnf(eq)
    args = defaultdict(list)
    for a in cnf.args:
        args[tuple(ordered(a.free_symbols))].append(a)
    _args = []
    for k in args:
        if len(k) == 1:
            _args.append(cnf.func(*args[k]).as_set().as_relational(k[0]))
        else:
            _args.append(cnf.func(*args[k]))
    return cnf.func(*_args)
```

For example:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import a, c
>>> f((a < 1) | ((c >= 4) & (a < 3) & (a < 12)))
(a < 3) & ((c >= 4) | (a < 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look in [sympy inequality solvers](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html#inequality-docs) for some options.

I could apply `reduce_inequalities` to your problem

```py
from sympy.abc import a, c
import sympy.solvers.inequalities as neq
t = neq.reduce_inequalities([a < 12, a < 3, c >= 4])
```

And it results
`(4 <= c) & (-oo < a) & (a < 3) & (c < oo)`

It also works with some more complex examples
[image]

as long as you have one variable per inequality.

Comment: Thank you, that works great! Is it also possible, though, to work out systems with alternative conditions (i.e., Boolean OR)? Like `((a < 12) & (c >= 4) & (a < 3)) | (a < 1)`

Comment: I am not sure if when you have only linear equations and you are intersecting them you have a simple domain. If you have a complicated logic I would try to put it in the conjunctive normal form, simplify each term separately. Then simplify the pairs of terms that have overlaps. But this is a whole new program.